# VBA chart range

Tags: vba, charts

How to plot a chart range?

A constains the value's name,
B "dates, which is not needed to plot",
C,E,D  are integers such as 1,2,3 etc,
when i try this code, it also plot the column "B"  which is not selected.

```
Dim rango1, rango2 As String
rango1 = "A2:A3"
rango2 = "C2:E3"
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(rango1, rango2)
```

Comment: Did you want rango1 to be a `Variant`? If you want it to be defined as a `String`, Dim is like this instead `Dim rango1 As String, rango2 As String`

Comment: rango2 is equal to "B2:E3"  except it isn't in your code and also you state that B contains dates that are not plotted.

Comment: Why not use the macro recorder to record the code as you create the desired chart off your existing data?

Comment: both variables are strings with the range that contains the data.

Comment: Your code creates a chart. What is the exact problem?

Comment: it should not select the column "b" and it's data

Comment: @alex - in questions like this and in general in Excel questions a screenshot helps a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that worked for me:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()        
    Dim rango1 As Range, rango2 As Range
    Dim django As Range
    Set rango1 = Range("A2:A3")
    Set rango2 = Range("C2:E3")
    Set django = Union(rango1, rango2)
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select        
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(django.Address)    
End Sub
```

Indeed, it is strange, that if you write

`ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(rango1, rango2)`

it will select the column `B` in the middle as well. Hopefully the developers of Excel had their reasons for it.

Answer (score 0):

And for me the following

```
Sub makechart()

Dim rango1 As String, rango2 As String
rango1 = "A2:A3"

rango2 = "C2:E3"

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select

Dim myStr As String

myStr = rango1 & "," & rango2

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(myStr) 

End Sub
```